# Error $Proxy811 when invoking UI

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a basic script which creates a UI.  I have reduced it to the following:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = new UiApp.createApplication();

  return app;
}
```

This throws the error:

> Method "createApplication" was invoked with [object Object] as "this" value that can not be converted to type $Proxy811. (line 2)

When run from the script edit page, and when published as a web app

Comment: What can be the interest of such an empty function ?

Comment: @Serge insas. I am not the question starter. For sure the function is useless, but I can assume it is a minimum function to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @megabyte1024 :I just think this question reflects an absence of pre-information on how things are supposed to work, as you stated in your answer the syntax is wrong, that's all ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `new` from the 1st function line, i.e. the function should be

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  return app;
}
```